# spark scala Join Dataset wit Seq[caseclass]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, case-class

I have been trying to create a new Dataset which contain an existing Dataset and Seq[Case class] where condition cid present in both of them.
There might be unique cid with multiple tid, trying to find out total transaction(money) done by individual cid.

```
  case class Data1(
                       cid: String,
                       fname: String,
                       add: String
                     )

  case class Data2(
                      cid: String,
                      tid: String,
                      money: Long
                    )
```

I have read csv into data1DF and data2DF, later created data1DS and data2DS with case class

```
data1DS: Dataset[Data1] = data1DF.as[Data1]
data2DS: Dataset[Data2] = data2DF.as[Data2]
```

I tried making Seq[Data2] and join wit the data1DF, it throws error.

```
val dd : Seq[Data2] = data2DS.collect().toSeq

val ansDS = data1DS.join(dd, data1DS("cid") === dd("cid"), "leftouter")

<console>:36: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("cid")
 required: Int
```

Comment: Datasets cannot be joined with Seq. You can use "data2DS" in join instead of "dd". Or convert "dd" to Dataset: val dd = data2DS.collect().toSeq.toDS()

Comment: @pasha701 The conversion `dd` to Dataset is bad idea, because you already have it in `data2DS` variable.

Comment: @pasha701 shud i create a new case class which like
`case class Table(Seq[Data2])`
then create a new Dataset and join it ?

Comment: @sierikov any lead/idea to how to proceed ahead ?

Comment: Such construction can be used:
val ansDS = data1DS.join(data2DS, data1DS("cid") === data2DS("cid"), "leftouter")

Comment: @Stunner-got-me pasha701 has good example